# How to rotate image before save in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-imaging-library

Now I'm creating a web app which allows user to upload images using Django Rest Framework.
I'd like to rotate those images according to EXIF tag and save.

At first, I found [this way](https://medium.com/@giovanni_cortes/rotate-image-in-django-when-saved-in-a-model-8fd98aac8f2a), and it works in local environment.
But, now I use Amazon S3 for deployment, then this way doesn't work.

So, I'm trying to rotate image before save and struggling... Recent code is below, raising `TypeError at /api/work/ 'str' object is not callable` when I post new Work object.

How to fix it?
Or is there other nice way?

[models.py]

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from PIL import Image as Img
from PIL import ExifTags
from io import BytesIO
from django.core.files import File
import datetime


class Work(models.Model):
    owner       = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    made_date   = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today, null=True, blank=True)
    note        = models.TextField(max_length=2000, null=True, blank=True)
    image       = models.ImageField(upload_to='work_pic', default='default_image.png')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.image:
            pilImage = Img.open(BytesIO(self.image.read()))
            for orientation in ExifTags.TAGS.keys():
                if ExifTags.TAGS[orientation] == 'Orientation':
                    break
            exif = dict(pilImage._getexif().items())

            if exif[orientation] == 3:
                pilImage = pilImage.rotate(180, expand=True)
            elif exif[orientation] == 6:
                pilImage = pilImage.rotate(270, expand=True)
            elif exif[orientation] == 8:
                pilImage = pilImage.rotate(90, expand=True)

            output = BytesIO()
            pilImage.save(output, format='JPEG', quality=75)
            output.seek(0)
            self.image = File(output, self.image.name())

        return super(Work, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

[serializers.py]

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Work


class WorkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

    class Meta:
        model = Work
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Work.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Comment: CAn you add the full traceback of your error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your **`save()`** method, you are calling the *`self.image.name`* attribute as a function. the `Image.name` is a `string` attribute, so you don't have to call it as a function.
So change the line
`self.image = File(output, self.image.name())` to
**`self.image = File(output, self.image.name)`**
 will solve the error

**Complete Model definition**

```
class Work(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    made_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today, null=True, blank=True)
    note = models.TextField(max_length=2000, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='work_pic', default='default_image.png')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.image:
            pilImage = Img.open(BytesIO(self.image.read()))
            for orientation in ExifTags.TAGS.keys():
                if ExifTags.TAGS[orientation] == 'Orientation':
                    break
            exif = dict(pilImage._getexif().items())

            if exif[orientation] == 3:
                pilImage = pilImage.rotate(180, expand=True)
            elif exif[orientation] == 6:
                pilImage = pilImage.rotate(270, expand=True)
            elif exif[orientation] == 8:
                pilImage = pilImage.rotate(90, expand=True)

            output = BytesIO()
            pilImage.save(output, format='JPEG', quality=75)
            output.seek(0)
            self.image = File(output, self.image.name)

        return super(Work, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This problem was totally solved!!